# How to split xml in different parts based on some element in WSO2 ESB

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, xslt-2.0, wso2-esb

I am trying to split incoming xml message in two messages and want to send on two different endpoints. like my message is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
```

```
<CMMHeader>   
    <MessageTimeStamp>2014-11-13T16:32:58.</MessageTimeStamp>
        <MessageId></MessageId> 
        <ComponentId>GLBooking</ComponentId> 
        <From>test</From> <To>GLBookingQueue</To> 
         <CorrelationId></CorrelationId>
        <ProcessId></ProcessId>
        <EventId></EventId> 
        <Domain>Finance</Domain> 
    </CMMHeader> 

    <tns:GLBooking> 
       <cdm:SubLedger >Payroll </cdm:SubLedger> 
       <cdm:Identifier>10004 </cdm:Identifier>
        <cdm:CreatedBy>test</cdm:CreatedBy>
         <cdm:CompanyCodeTo>3010</cdm:CompanyCodeTo>
          <cdm:PostingDate>20141009</cdm:PostingDate> 
          <cdm:CreationDate>20140901</cdm:CreationDate>
           <cdm:GLBookingLine> 
           <cdm:LineNumber>1</cdm:LineNumber> 
       <cdm:AccountNumber>0000133200</cdm:AccountNumber> 
    <cdm:Description> </cdm:Description> 
    <cdm:TaxCode> </cdm:TaxCode> 
    <cdm:CostCenter> </cdm:CostCenter> 
           <cdm:Currency>EUR</cdm:Currency> 
    <cdm:Amount>00000840213</cdm:Amount> 
    <cdm:DebetCredit>C</cdm:DebetCredit>
            <cdm:BaseAmount>00000000000</cdm:BaseAmount>
    </cdm:GLBookingLine>
             <cdm:GLBookingLine>
              <cdm:LineNumber>2</cdm:LineNumber> 
    <cdm:AccountNumber>0000133205</cdm:AccountNumber>
               <cdm:Description> </cdm:Description> 
    <cdm:TaxCode> </cdm:TaxCode>
                <cdm:CostCenter> </cdm:CostCenter> 
    <cdm:Currency>EUR</cdm:Currency> 
                <cdm:Amount>00000213120</cdm:Amount>
    <cdm:DebetCredit>C</cdm:DebetCredit>
                 <cdm:BaseAmount>00000000000</cdm:BaseAmount> 
    </cdm:GLBookingLine> 
   </tns:GLBooking> 
</GLBookingMessage>
</soapenv:Body>
                 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to split this message into two mesage.

```
<CMMHeader>   
    <MessageTimeStamp>2014-11-13T16:32:58.</MessageTimeStamp>
        <MessageId></MessageId> 
        <ComponentId>GLBookingFileAdapter</ComponentId> 
        <From>test</From> <To>GLBookingQueue</To> 
         <CorrelationId></CorrelationId>
        <ProcessId></ProcessId>
        <EventId></EventId> 
        <Domain>Finance</Domain> 
    </CMMHeader>
```

and

```
<GLBookingMessage>
 <tns:GLBooking> 
           <cdm:SubLedger >Payroll </cdm:SubLedger> 
           <cdm:Identifier>10004 </cdm:Identifier>
            <cdm:CreatedBy>test</cdm:CreatedBy>
             <cdm:CompanyCodeTo>3010</cdm:CompanyCodeTo>
              <cdm:PostingDate>20141009</cdm:PostingDate> 
              <cdm:CreationDate>20140901</cdm:CreationDate>
               <cdm:GLBookingLine> 
               <cdm:LineNumber>1</cdm:LineNumber> 
           <cdm:AccountNumber>0000133200</cdm:AccountNumber> 
        <cdm:Description> </cdm:Description> 
        <cdm:TaxCode> </cdm:TaxCode> 
        <cdm:CostCenter> </cdm:CostCenter> 
               <cdm:Currency>EUR</cdm:Currency> 
        <cdm:Amount>00000840213</cdm:Amount> 
        <cdm:DebetCredit>C</cdm:DebetCredit>
                <cdm:BaseAmount>00000000000</cdm:BaseAmount>
        </cdm:GLBookingLine>
                 <cdm:GLBookingLine>
                  <cdm:LineNumber>2</cdm:LineNumber> 
        <cdm:AccountNumber>0000133205</cdm:AccountNumber>
                   <cdm:Description> </cdm:Description> 
        <cdm:TaxCode> </cdm:TaxCode>
                    <cdm:CostCenter> </cdm:CostCenter> 
        <cdm:Currency>EUR</cdm:Currency> 
                    <cdm:Amount>00000213120</cdm:Amount>
        <cdm:DebetCredit>C</cdm:DebetCredit>
                     <cdm:BaseAmount>00000000000</cdm:BaseAmount> 
        </cdm:GLBookingLine> 
       </tns:GLBooking> 
    </GLBookingMessage>
```

Please help me. it will be a great favour.

Comment: Can you post your XSLT here.

Comment: I am trying to do it in WSO2 ESB. I have no idea how xslt will work in this scenario, thats why i have not posted the xslt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inSequence, clone the message

In each target, transform your message as needed and send the new message to the corresponding endpoint

Sample using payloadFactory in 1st target (message with CMMHeader only) and javascript in the 2nd (message without CMMHeader) :

```
<clone>
    <target>
        <sequence>
            <payloadFactory>
                <format>
                    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <soapenv:Body>$1</soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope> 
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg expression="//CMMHeader"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <log level="full"/>
        </sequence>
    </target>
    <target>
        <sequence>
            <script language="js">
                mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstElement().detach();
            </script> 
            <log level="full"/>
        </sequence>
    </target>
</clone>
```

replace 'log' with 'send' mediator

You can use XSLT to apply your transformation